# Unable to use git authenication for private repo pip install

Tags: python, git, github, pip, azure-devops

I'm using azure devops for building a python project where we have a requirements.txt that references private git repositories.

These repos are under the same github account that our devops account has access to, but are unable to get them using pip.

I notice that the 'Get sources' step adds an extra header to git commands:

[command]git -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: basic ***" fetch --tags --prune --progress --no-recurse-submodules origin

Is there any way that we can get this header into other steps to allow us to use the same authentication for private pip installation or otherwise access private git repositories that devops already has access to?

**I do not want to use personal access tokens, or deploy keys as it just another layer of security to be maintained and managed. Azure devops already has authentication to these repositories and we should be able to use this.**